# Quality standard... What is it?

Tags: support

This happens many times (to me) in meta... (Now, it happened 5 times) What does it mean by "Oops! This question cannot be submitted because, It doesn't meet our quality standards". And, at last, it's verifying me for a Robot? (Doesn't this irritate for comparing a humanoid?)

What's your quality standard? I mean, Is there any rules for asking "Help Me.."?

Comment: Same comment as always: things that affect the entire network are discussed on the mother meta. That's meta.stackoverflow for now but will eventually move to meta.stackexchange. When you ask *"What is [some feature of the network]?"* on a site specific meta you are only going to get a re-direct to the mother meta. Try searching for `"quality standard" [faq]` over there.

Answer (score 3):

This is described [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards). Here's the gist:

> Make sure your question has
>
> - a clear title
> - a reasonable explanation of what your question is, sharing your research on the matter
> - correct use of English and actual sentences

Of course that's not an exhaustive list of what makes a good (or rather, non-bad) question, just some general guidelines.